# AJAX url Request Loop

Tags: ajax, url, request

how can i loop url request in ajax if i get a particular error, i will check the status in loop if the request is success then inside the loop there will be an if state ment, if success do something, if not do something... and also it must have a delay before the next url request

For example

isSuccess will hold the value if its request is sucess

```
While !(isSuccess=="success"){

ajax url request here

 if success {
 do someting
 }
 else
 {
 do something
 }
 delay code here
}
```

I hope someone can help me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you Can use **recursion as a Ajax loop**

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    reqUrl = "UrlString For ajax Request";
    $.post(reqUrl, function (response) {
           if (response.success) 
           {
             // Do something
           }
          else
          {
             // Do something
             ajaxFunction();
           }

    });
}
```

A request will only be sent when a previous request is compleated. Evan if you want delay in that you can use `setTimeout(ajaxFunction,3000);`

Comment: its a loop man ... a function calling itself is a loop. when you call it first time it will send a ajax request ... when this request compleats it will call itseld and send another request... it will continue sending request till the response.success is not true... once its true it will stop.